# removing a pervious object from an array and retaining the latest object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a react js form which takes input from the user

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import '../../../assets/styles/modal.scss'
import closeIcon from '../../../images/icons/Icon2.png'


export const CreateAft = (props) => {
  const [state,setState]=useState({aircraft:"",variant:"",type:"",firstClass:false,fcCap:null,businessClass:false,bcCap:null,premEcon:false,peCap:null,econ:false,ecCap:null})
  const [classCapacity,setClassCapacity]=useState([]);
  const [save,setSave]=useState(false)

    const aircraftTypeList = [
    {key: 0, label: "Select Type", value: ''},
    {key: 1, label: "Long Haul", value: 'longHaul'},
    {key: 2, label: "Short Haul", value: 'shortHaul'}
  ]

  useEffect(() => {

      if(state.firstClass &&state.fcCap){
        setClassCapacity(( currentValue ) => [ ...currentValue, {classCode: "fc", seatCapacity: state.fcCap, className: "First Class"} ])
      }
      if(state.businessClass &&state.bcCap){
        setClassCapacity(( currentValue ) => [ ...currentValue, {classCode: "bc", seatCapacity: state.bcCap, className: "Business Class"} ])
      }
      if(state.premEcon &&state.peCap){
        setClassCapacity(( currentValue ) => [ ...currentValue, {classCode: "pc", seatCapacity: state.peCap, className: "Premium Economy"} ])
      }
      if(state.econ &&state.ecCap){
        setClassCapacity(( currentValue ) => [ ...currentValue, {classCode: "ec", seatCapacity: state.ecCap, className: "Economy"} ])
      }

  }, [save])

  console.log("object",classCapacity);

  const onChangeInputs=(e)=>{
const {name,value}=e.target;
switch (name) {
  case "aircraft":
    setState((_prev) => {
      return { ..._prev, aircraft:value };
  });

    break;
    case "variant":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, variant:value };
    });
    break;
    case "type":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, type:value};
    });
    break;
    case "firstClass":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, firstClass:!state.firstClass };
    });
    break;
    case "businessClass":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, businessClass:!state.businessClass };
    });
    break;

    case "premEcon":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, premEcon:!state.premEcon };
    });
    break;

    case "economy":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, econ:!state.econ };
    });
    break;

    case "fcCap":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, fcCap:value };
    });
    break;

    case "bcCap":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, bcCap:value };
    });
    break;

    case "peCap":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, peCap:value };
    });
    break;

    case "ecCap":
      setState((_prev) => {
        return { ..._prev, ecCap:value};
    });
    break;
  default:
    setState((_prev) => {
      return { ..._prev };
  });
    break;
}
  }

  const onSaveAircraftDetails=async()=>{
setSave(!save);

   const body= {
      model: state.aircraft,
      variant:state.variant,
      aircraftType: state.type==='longHaul'?'Long haul':'Shorrt haul',
      classCapacity:classCapacity
  }

    try {

          }
        catch (error) {

        }

         }


  return (
      <div className="overlay" role="dialog">
      <div className="dialog sm-scrollbar">
        <div className="dialog__content">
          <img className="modal__close_icon" alt='Close' src={closeIcon} onClick={props.onClose} />
          <h2 className="dialog__title subheading-text-medium fontMedium">{props.title}</h2>
          <hr />
          <div className="dialog__body_container flexRow justifyContentSpaceBetween flexWrap">
            <div className="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
              <div className=" dialog__container_item input-container">
                <div className="dialog__description">
                  <label className="req">Aircraft</label>
                  <input
                    id='aircraft'
                    type={'text'}
                    name="aircraft"
                    placeholder={'Aircraft'}
                    value={state.aircraft}
                    onChange={onChangeInputs}
                    className='edit-input'
                    />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
              <div className=" dialog__container_item input-container">
                <div className="dialog__description">
                  <label className="req">Variant</label>
                  <input
                    id='variant'
                    name="variant"
                    placeholder={'variant'}
                    type={'text'}
                    value={state.variant}
                    onChange={onChangeInputs}
                    className='edit-input'
                    />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div className="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly ">
              <div className=" dialog__container_item input-container">
                <div className="dialog__description">
                  <label className="req">Type</label>
                  <select className='select-input' name='type' onChange={onChangeInputs} value={state.type}>
              {
                aircraftTypeList.map((_, index) => {
                    return (
                      <option value={_.value} key={index}>{_.label}</option>
                    )
                })
              }
            </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

<div className='flexRow margTop36'>
    <div className='width50'>
       <div className="flexCol justifyContentCenter ">
              <div className={`dialog__container_item input-container margTop16 margLeft19`}>
              <div className={`dialog__description__checkbox`}>
              <input
                id={1}
                type={'checkbox'}
                name='firstClass'
                onClick={onChangeInputs}
                checked={state.firstClass}
                value={state.firstClass}
              />
              <label htmlFor={1} className={`margTop8`} >First Class</label>
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div className='width50'>
    <div className="flexCol justifyContentCenter ">
              <div className=" dialog__container_item input-container aircraft_modal">
                <div className="dialog__description">
                   <label className='aircraft_modal'>Capacity:</label>
                  <input
                    id='type'
                    name="fcCap"
                    placeholder={'capacity'}
                    type={'number'}
                    value={state.fcCap}
                    onChange={onChangeInputs}
                    className='edit-input-galley-aircraft'
                    />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div className='flexRow margTop24'>
    <div className='width50'>
    <div className="flexCol justifyContentCenter ">
              <div className={`dialog__container_item input-container margTop16 margLeft19`}>
              <div className={`dialog__description__checkbox`}>
              <input
                id={''}
                type={'checkbox'}
                name='businessClass'
                onClick={onChangeInputs}
                checked={state.businessClass}
                value={state.businessClass}
              />
              <label htmlFor={1} className={`margTop8`} >Business Class</label>
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <div className='width50'>
    <div className="flexCol justifyContentCenter ">
              <div className=" dialog__container_item input-container aircraft_modal">
                <div className="dialog__description">
                   <label className='aircraft_modal' >Capacity:</label>
                  <input
                    id='type'
                    name="bcCap"
                    placeholder={'capacity'}
                    type={'number'}
                    value={state.bcCap}
                    onChange={onChangeInputs}
                    className='edit-input-galley-aircraft'
                    />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>


</div>
<div className='flexRow margTop24'>
    <div className='width50'>
    <div className="flexCol justifyContentCenter ">
              <div className={`dialog__container_item input-container margTop16 margLeft19`}>
              <div className={`dialog__description__checkbox`}>
              <input
                id={''}
                type={'checkbox'}
                name='premEcon'
                onClick={onChangeInputs}
                checked={state.premEcon}
                value={state.premEcon}
              />
              <label htmlFor={1} className={`margTop8`} >Premium Economy</label>
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <div className='width50'>
    <div className="flexCol justifyContentCenter ">
              <div className=" dialog__container_item input-container aircraft_modal">
                <div className="dialog__description">
                   <label className='aircraft_modal'>Capacity:</label>
                  <input
                    id='type'
                    name="peCap"
                    placeholder={'capacity'}
                    type={'number'}
                    value={state.peCap}
                    onChange={onChangeInputs}
                    className='edit-input-galley-aircraft'
                    />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>


</div>
<div className='flexRow margTop24'>
    <div className='width50'>
    <div className="flexCol justifyContentCenter ">
              <div className={`dialog__container_item input-container margTop16 margLeft19`}>
              <div className={`dialog__description__checkbox`}>
              <input
                id={''}
                type={'checkbox'}
                name='economy'
                onClick={onChangeInputs}
                checked={state.econ}
                value={state.econ}
              />
              <label htmlFor={1} className={`margTop8`} >Economy</label>
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div className='width50'>
    <div className="flexCol justifyContentCenter ">
              <div className=" dialog__container_item input-container aircraft_modal">
                <div className="dialog__description">
                  <label className='aircraft_modal'>Capacity:</label>
                  <input
                    id='type'
                    name="ecCap"
                    placeholder={'capacity'}
                    type={'number'}
                    value={state.ecCap}
                    onChange={onChangeInputs}
                    className='edit-input-galley-aircraft'
                    />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>


     </div>

     <div className="dialog__footer flexCol alignItemsCenter margTop24">
          <button  disabled={false} className="done-button" onClick={onSaveAircraftDetails}>Save</button>
        </div>

         {/* {Boolean(updateStatusText) ?
          <>
            <div className={ "dialog__statusBlock " + (isError ? 'alert_error' : 'alert_success') }>
              {updateStatusText}
            </div>
          </> : null } */}
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export const CreateAircraft = (props) => {


  const onClose = (e) => {
    removeContainerOverlay();
    props.onClose();
  }

  const removeContainerOverlay = () => {
    /**
     * Remove overlay to parent class
     */
    (document.querySelectorAll('.content-container')[0]).classList.remove('modal-overlay-bg2');
  };

  return (
    <CreateAft
     title={props.title}
      onClose={onClose}
      >
    </CreateAft>
  )
}
```

i am trying to save specific user input in an array classCapacity onclick of save by toggling the save state in useEffect.I am obtaining same object as the user submit the modified form.My intention is to retain the latest object in the on submit by the  user and remove the previous ones,Is there a right approach to do this?